# Blazor Wasm standalone authentication with KeyCloak

Tags: authentication, keycloak, reverse-proxy, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor Wasm standalone app where i'm trying to use authentication through KeyCloak.

When i press the login button i get redirected to keycloak, i login with a user i created in keycloak, get redirected back to the app but i'm not logged in.

What i've done:

- Create new Blazor Wasm app (.Net 6.0), choose Individual accounts as authentication type, tick boxes configure for HTTPS and Progressive Web Application
- In Program.cs add following code

```
    builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
    {
        builder.Configuration.Bind("oidc", options.ProviderOptions);
        options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("profile");
    });
```

- Add following to appsettings.json

```
    "oidc": {
        "Authority": "https://MyAuthority",
        "ClientId": "MyClientID",
        "RedirectUri": "https://localhost:5192",
        "ResponseMode": "query",
        "ResponseType": "code" //I have tried id_token
     }
```

- In Keycloak i have set these settings

  - Valid redirect URIs: https://localhost:5192/*
  - Implicit flow: on
  - Client authentication: off

I think i should mention that the keycloak runs in a container behind a reverse proxy (traefik). And everything behind the reverse proxy uses http.

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

I think in the client configuration in  your Keycloak "Valid Redirect URLs" you are missing an entry for your  application
[image: Keycloak Client Settings]